# Trying to understand what this python class is doing/how it works

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and looking at code other people wrote. I found a neat program that generates music in python and I really want to understand what it's doing (link/credit here: http://davywybiral.blogspot.com.br/2010/09/procedural-music-with-pyaudio-and-numpy.html).

Specifically, I'm hung up on this variable `intervals` that belongs to a class at the beginning of the program. Here is the class:

```
class Scale:

  def __init__(self, root, intervals):
    self.root = Note(root.index, 0)
    self.intervals = intervals

  def get(self, index):
    intervals = self.intervals
    if index < 0:
      index = abs(index)
      intervals = reversed(self.intervals)
    intervals = itertools.cycle(self.intervals)
    note = self.root
    for i in xrange(index):
      note = note.transpose(intervals.next())
    return note

  def index(self, note):
    intervals = itertools.cycle(self.intervals)
    index = 0
    x = self.root
    while x.octave != note.octave or x.note != note.note:
      x = x.transpose(intervals.next())
      index += 1
    return index

  def transpose(self, note, interval):
    return self.get(self.index(note) + interval)
```

At the end of the program there are instructions for the program to play certain chords and the following is written:

```
scale = Scale(root, [2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1])
```

It's the second argument that I'm unclear on; I understand that the program is cycling through these values, but I don't know what they're controlling. I just know that changing them messes with the pitches, often for the worst.

Can I get some guidance on what's happening with these lines?

Comment: Well, it's the intervals between the notes, just as it says. That is a harmonic minor scale.

Comment: I should say, you will likely need to know some things about music to understand this program. If you don't, for example, understand what an interval or a scale is, you will probably get lost very quickly.

Comment: I know music well, but I do not know python well. Perhaps some more specific questions would be helpful. What is happening in the class `Scale`? And why does the scale have to be called every time a chord is made in the lines following? I assure you this is a question about the code and not a question about music theory...

Comment: I only see one call to `Scale` in that code...

Comment: In the lines following the assignment `scale`, there are lines such as: `chunks.append(chord(21, scale) + pluck2(scale.get(38)))`. `chord` is a chord, `pluck` is a single frequency, the numbers correspond to different pitches. There is a reference back to the object `scale`

Answer (score 0):

The values are the intervals between the notes. So in this case:
2 1 2 2 1 3 1, which according to the explanation given on the link you provided is the harmonic minor (also see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_scale#Harmonic_minor_scale)).

So if you change the numbers you change the distance/interval between the notes and with that the scale.

Assume root is an A, the following scale is provided:

```
A B C D E F G# A    Actual notes
 2 1 2 2 1 3  1     The intervals between the notes
```

In case the list would be [2 1 2 2 1 2 1] the scale would be minor:

```
A B C D E F G A  Actual notes
 2 1 2 2 1 2 1   The intervals between the notes
```

So if you want to give it a C-major scale you should give in:

```
C D E F G A B C in a list of intervals:
 2 2 1 2 2 2 1
```

I hope this helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Central to this code is the idea of iterators.  Iterators are "pointers" into a list, e.g. of intervals, that are used to move through the list.
e.g.

```
for i in [1, 2, 3]:
    print i
```

That code iterates through the list [1, 2, 3] and prints..
1
2
3

While an iterator lets you "count" through a list, lists are automatically converted into iterators if you need an iterator.

So this code is using the interval list and various iterators interchangeably in the code in get()..  which is confusing. It's basically doing a bunch of ordered shuffling of the notes.

This is roughly what it does (I know as much about music as you do about programming :).  Looks like it'll sound like Bach.

```
class Scale:   # class declaration.

  def __init__(self, root, intervals):
    """
    __init__ is the constructor.  It gets called automatically
    whenever a new instance is created.  That is, it's called 
    automatically when a new Scale is made, e.g. on this line:

      scale = Scale(root, [2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1]) 

    """
    self.root = Note(root.index, 0)  # the root is a note?
    self.intervals = intervals # this just saves the list [2, 1,..

  def get(self, index):
    """
    called whenever someone goes.. scale.get(index) or within
    this class it's called as self.get(index).

    """
    # get a reference to the intervals (no copy is made)
    # at this point we could iterate over it from the start of the
    # intervals to the end of the intervals e.g. 2, 1, 2, 2, ..
    intervals = self.intervals  

    # if the index is less than zero 
    if index < 0:  
      # get the absolute value, e.g. -5 goes to 5
      index = abs(index)

      # makes intervals an iterator that counts backwards
      # e.g. [1, 3, 1, 2...] 
      # this "mirrors" the intervals if you like
      intervals = reversed(self.intervals)

    # makes intervals "loop forever" you can keep iterating and 
    # when you get to the end, loop around to the start again.
    intervals = itertools.cycle(self.intervals)

    # swap this note with the next index notes
    note = self.root
    for i in xrange(index):
      note = note.transpose(intervals.next())
    return note

  def index(self, note):
    """
    Finds the index of the next note and transposes 
    a bunch of them to.

    """
    intervals = itertools.cycle(self.intervals)
    index = 0
    x = self.root
    # keep trying notes until we have a different note in 
    # this octave
    while x.octave != note.octave or x.note != note.note:
      x = x.transpose(intervals.next())
      index += 1
    return index

  def transpose(self, note, interval):
    """
    Gets the note one interval away.
    Which also transposes a bunch of things.

    """
    return self.get(self.index(note) + interval)
```